# Schottky diode as AM detector?

Tags: repair, schottky

An old AM radio that passed down to me from my grandparents finally ceased to function after I accidentally dropped it and old parts inside got damaged. I ripped all damaged parts out and replaced them with modern equivalents. There is one thing I am having trouble replacing: the detector diode.

The original diode is `2AP9` (Chinese part, was THE detector diode in Chinese radio designs, similar to `1N34A`,) a germanium detector diode that got shattered. I don't have any germanium parts any more (the germanium PNP transistors was replaced with silicon ones, but the amplifier is adjusted accordingly to make them work correctly after a few resistors get replaced)

However I do have a few Schottky rectifiers `1N5819`. Are those good enough as detector diodes in AM radio? Do I need to adjust some caps and resistors to compensate the 110pF junction capacitance? (`2AP9` have 1pF)

Comment: I guess a BAT85 would be a better try. Maybe you have a G transistor left from which you could use the BE junction?

Comment: I dumped and replaced all old transistors actually. The `3AG1`'s have a planar BE junction and I am a bit worried about its junction capacitance. Those old parts didn't have such a specification!

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen That radio is older than me! I wouldn't trust anything in it at all (maybe except the PCB board itself) but I just didn't bother to replace all the caps and resistors.

Comment: Why not just try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 2AP9 is similar to 1N34A, you can [surely still find those](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/105597/1n34-1n270-obsolete), although I'm not sure about availability in China (your location).

As for using Schottkys as substitute, [1N5711](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1470783.pdf) (a ~0.2V [@ 25C] UHF Schottky) does work as substitute in [some designs](http://www.eham.net/ehamforum/smf/index.php?ehamsid=9gnk93f95hvtoafrhthkeu0sd2&topic=87236.msg645011#msg645011); 1N5711 has only 2pF capacitance. YMMV if it will actually work in your radio, but it seems to have a better chance than 1N5819.

There are some [research papers](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/JSSC.2007.894300) on using (CMOS-fabricated) Schottkys as ultrawide-band AM detectors: "The input and output matching of the detector is better than -10 dB from 0-10.3 GHz". I'm guessing that a worry might be getting too much band and thus possibly HF noise when using a Schottky instead of a Ge diode for an AM radio in the classic AM radio band.

Comment: +1 Lots of 1N34A diodes offered from China these days. Presumably they're not all rebadged 1N4148s. Maybe a BAT62 (0.35pF typical at 0V).

Comment: Yes [BAT62](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BAT62SERIES-DS-v01_01-en.pdf?folderId=5546d4694909da4801490a07012f053b&fileId=db3a304314dca3890115181141bf0df3) has even better-looking stats capacitance-wise as you say (and about the same 0.2V drop at 25C). But the OP might not like that it is only a surface-mount part. Trying to adapt it to an old THT board might end up adding significant parasitic capacitance.

Comment: Those selling "`1N34A`" offers rebadged `1N4148` at inflated prices and the 0.7V drop will probably eat away the signal completely, since the receiver resonator is pretty weak. The board is probably 25-30 years old so it was all single sided THT. I will give `1N5711` a go.