# 1N270 Spice Model

Tags: diodes, spice

Does anyone have the spice model for the 1N270 Germanium Diode?
I have found several online libraries of spice models for diodes, but none of them have the 1N270. A google search didn't find it, although I found a couple of postings where the author used a model for 1N270, so I think it must exist somewhere.
I am using ngspice, but I think any spice model would be usable for me.

Comment: You could use the 1N34A model, much more easily found, which is a germanium diode as well: .MODEL 1N34A D(bv=75 cjo=0.5e-12 eg=0.67 ibv=18e-3 is=2e-7 rs=7 n=1.3 vj=0.1 m=0.27). Some guy [plotted](http://www.cliftonlaboratories.com/diode_vf_vs_if.htm) both this model's characteristics and the real 1N270, and it's close enough.

Comment: And, by the way, I'd avoid designing circuits with those anyway, since they're [unobtainium](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/105597/1n34-1n270-obsolete)

Comment: I just bought 20...
I have seen other people substituting other diodes for this one in spice, but I thought someone should have the actual model for this one.

Comment: [1N270 on Jameco](https://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10001_10001_35941_-1)

Comment: Ok... Still thinking you could use some schottky. Looking at the datasheet, it doesn't seem 1N270 performances are better than BAT41...

Comment: I am making distortion circuits for guitar. So yes, I also have some  Schottky diodes. They do sound different. Anyway, I have some ideas about how to get better sounding harmonic distortion, but to actually use some engineering to get there it would be nice to have models for the components...

Comment: Ha!! I knew it was for guitar effects... You guys are the last people on earth to use those germanium diodes. Ok, fine, if they *sound different*, then :)

Comment: I guess I can use the data sheet to derive the Is, etc...just surprised this model is not available.